# virtual memory exhausted: Cannot allocate memory with 8 gb ram

Tags: c++, memory, makefile, compiler-errors, compilation

I have code which is 32 bit and i think compiler too. But when i am compiling my c++ code, its taking more than 2 GB memory. As per my understanding on 32 bit system no process can take more than 2 GB.
Any suggestions how can i achieve this? I found lot of posts on this but those
are not helpful as they are adding swaps. But i already have 8 GB ram. So my   problem is not available memory, its size of compiling process which could not be   more than 2 GB.

Even i have 8 GB ram I have  tried to adding swap and that's also not working.

Comment: the virtual address space available to each process is only 2 gigs.  The other 2 giigs are reserved for the operating system to use as it sees fit. There's a way in windows to make it 3 gigs if you google for it.  It doesn't matter how much ram or swap you have in your computer.  Better, just install a 64-bit OS and don't worry about it anymore.

Comment: What is the "size of compiling process"? What is your question actually? Suggestion to achieve what? Are you asking how to improve the space efficiency of your program, without pasting any code? Or are you asking how to switch from 32-bit to 64-bit? *As per my understanding on 32 bit system no process can take more than 2 GB* - yes, this understanding is (more or less) correct, unless you want to force users of your program to boot their windows with the `/3TB` parameter.

Comment: Ditch your 32 bit OS and compiler.

Comment: Apart from ditching the 32 bit OS & compiler, you might also want to split your compilation units. If your compiler needs over 2 GiB memory, then your compilation units are much bigger than I would ever allow them to get. Too large compilation units are a problem that causes a too long compile-test-change cycle by requiring too much code to be recompiled on every iteration, which is a major obstacle to productivity. The same code in twice as many compilation units of half the size will save you tons of time.

Comment: You have tagged your question with `c++` `makefile` `compiler-errors` but there is no C++ code, no makefile, and no compiler errors cited.

Comment: @Groo : My code compilation is failing and error message that i am getting is "virtual memory exhausted: Cannot allocate memory". An please note am compiling code on unix using g++ (GCC) 4.9.3.

Comment: Impossible to tell, you haven't posted any code, no details about the size of your project, no makefile, you haven't even specified the compiler/IDE you're using. Perhaps you are using some messed up templates, we can only guess. Perhaps you are just including everything everywhere and it's a large project, we can only guess.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows 32 Bit, the maximum amount of RAM is 4 GB. By default, this address space is seperated into kernel memory and process memory, both being 2 GB large. Most programs don't need more than 2 GB of memory, but if you do, you can enlarge the process memory by specifying the /3GB switch, leaving less memory for the kernel.

Read here for more information: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff556232(v=vs.85).aspx

Edit: Keep in mind that if you want to make use of this additional memory, you also need to compile your program with the /LARGEADDRESSAWARE switch. That will set a flag in the Process Environment Block of your program, making Windows aware that your program might need more than 2 GB of memory.

Answer (score 0):

Since you stated you have 8GB of RAM, I am presuming your OS and CPU are actually 64-bit. So you are asking how to make a 32-bit program access more than 2GB of virtual address space, on a 64-bit OS, i.e. running under WOW64.

In that case, using the [`/LARGEADDRESSAWARE` linker option](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz223b1z.aspx) in Visual Studio will give your app **4GB** of virtual address space, [under WOW64](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384219(v=vs.85).aspx). You won't see any benefit in 32-bit Windows, unless you force your users to boot their OS with a certain flag.

I believe your app doesn't really need more than 2GB of RAM, but it's impossible to tell without knowing any details.

In any case, the one correct answer is: switch to a 64-bit app, which will get you 8TB of virtual address space. That's **8 terabytes**.